# Solutions of non-linear congruence equation

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I am trying to find the number of solution to

$$   x^a(\mod b) =c:0\leq x\leq l$$

where $b\leq50$ but $a$ and $l$ can be large. My approach is to iterate through each value of $x$ from $0$ till $\min(b,l)$, and if it satisfies the equation add $ceil(\frac{l-x}b)$ (to account for the number of values of $x$ is are greater than $b$ but are equivalent in multiplicative field of $b$)  to the number of solutions. I am not sure about the correctness of my algorithm. And can I extend my approach to to more than one variable like if there is

$$(x^a + y^a) (\mod b)=c$$

I can produce all unordered pairs of x and y such that $x\leq y$ till $(x,y)\leq \min(b,l)$ and again calculate $i=ceil(\frac{l-x}b)$ and $j=ceil(\frac{l-y}b)$ and multiply add the sum as :

$$t=\{i+i(i-1)\times2\text{ if }x=y , i\times j\times2\text{ if }x!=y \}$$

and take summation of t. I want to know if my algorithm is correct and if there is any other more efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several remarks:

1. Since you start iterating at $0$ you can (and should) stop at $b-1$, or $\min (b-1, l)$ to stay close to what you said.
2. It is not completely clear to me what you do when you mention the ceil as you say you add this to account for the values greater than $b$. The ceil you give is the *total* number of solutions you have corresponding to the one solution you found (but perhaps you meant this anyway).
3. Since you say that also $a$ can be large, you might want to exploit an additional way of saving iterations. For $x$ relatively prime to $b$ it is known that $x^{\varphi(b)}= 1 \pmod{b}$ where $\varphi$ denotes [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) (you could even use Carmichael's function instead, but this might not be worth the effort). So you can proceed regarding the exponent $a$ in the same as for the base $x$, but for the exponent calculate $\pmod{\varphi(b)}$ not modulo $b$. Yet note this works for $x$ coprime to $b$ only. But also for $x$ not coprime to $b$ the sequence $x^i$ is eventually periodic, so this would still work in principle.
4. Finally, do you know anything about the $c$. For example, if $c$ is coprime to $b$ you would know right away you can restrict to $x$ coprime. Conversely if it is not you can also restrict $x$ to not  coprime and even more could be said.

And, yes, for more than one variable you could proceed like this, but for the case of equality I am a bit unsure why you ge the expression you get, I'd expect just $i^2$.

Regarding better alogorithms I am not sure, it also might depend on some things you did not make precise.

Comment: For two variables i have to list the ordered pairs so if x=y then i=j ,i.e, if I increment x and y by equal amount then I will get something like (a,a) which can be arranged in only one way and there can be only i such pairs , but if I increment x and y by different amount then a pair(a,b) will be formed each of which can be arranged in 2 ways but as increment is different then if I chose increment bk 0<=k<=ceil then I cannot chose the same k . Similar reasoning follows if x!=y.

Comment: As far as constraints are concerned there is no assumption on c(prime or not prime or even co prime to b) . We only know b<=50 and a and l are large.

Comment: Ok I was counting similar permutation multiple time the number of combination is indeed i^2. Thanks a lot for the reply.